# Did these parts come from a T-33 crash?

Tags: aircraft-identification

A [Lockheed T-33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_T-33) crashed near my hometown ([Outer Cove, Newfoundland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logy_Bay-Middle_Cove-Outer_Cove)) in 1956. This year we have had some very strong storm surges, and a piece of metal has washed up on the shore. I am posting this picture to see if anyone  can tell if it is part of the crashed T-33. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Am I right to assume the oval hole is approx. 2x8 inches?

Comment: Yes that is correct the are two on that piece.

Comment: oh hey, you found that old piece of dental work I lost when I was in NF last year...

Comment: @CiderJoe , awesome, do you know why they believe at the time it crashed?  IT would be amazing if you could find a bullet hole, fuel residue or whatever is relevant to the event!  Awesome idea on the museum.

Comment: They think it was weather. Here's the story on it if your interested.

Comment: https://www.pressreader.com/canada/the-telegram-st-johns/20150505/281500749811940

Comment: @CiderJoe -- did you ever get in touch w/ the guy who posted this answer on 4-6-2021, now deleted?  "I've also found two pieces of a aircraft from Outer Cove Beach within the last two days. I have pictures if you would like to see. I can email them."

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It looks like the nose skin panel with the gun ports that some T-33s had.  So I'd be willing to put serious money down on "yes".

[image: Lockheed T-33 Shooting Star ‘69330 / TR-330’ (N651)]
<sup>Lockheed T-33 Shooting Star ‘69330 / TR-330’ (N651)

Alan Wilson from Stilton, Peterborough, Cambs, UK</sup>

Comment: Damn you John, just as I was about to post an answer I noticed you were (way) faster. I totally agree with you, the top side is a bit different, but the rivet hole pattern on oval thingy are a match. So my money is on yes too.

Comment: Yeah a lot of posts are just races to Google Images aren't they lol.

Comment: It might be good to editorialize this answer a bit with what the questioner should _do_ about it -- is there someone who should be notified? Can they legally keep it as a souvenir or sell it to someone on eBay?

Comment: How come the lower right corner of the plate is cut so neatly in a diagonal line?

Comment: Wow that looks like it for sure. The plane slid about 40 feet and then slid down over a 200 foot clift. Thats

Comment: We have a museum that has a section on the plane crash so I will be donating it to them.

Comment: @GlennWillen Why? That wasn't part of the question.

Comment: @Mast It depends on local jurisdiction, but generally speaking, debris from a crashed plane is highly sought after by authorities and in some cases it may be illegal to possess, or you may be legally required to report it to the NTSB or whatever agency is responsible for aviation accidents in your jurisdiction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_archaeology explains more. This is especially important when it pertains to crashed military aircraft, as explained in the article.

Comment: @zovits that looks like a fold in the metal.  You can see a rivet hole right at the fold.

Comment: @Nzall Considering this is about Canada, asking the [TSB](https://www.tsb.gc.ca/eng/aviation/index.html) for advice won't hurt, although I'm not sure those care about military craft this old.

Comment: Seriously you guys?  It's a little piece of sheet metal from 1956!  The investigation closed its books on this one over 60 years ago, I doubt very much that there is a clue in this that any investigator could use to solve some lingering mystery about root cause.  There are far more compelling and recent crash sites with debris still out there that people no longer care about.  I would keep it as a souvenir or donate it with a clear conscience and not pay any attention to the naysayers.

Comment: @MichaelHall Calling people that recommend getting a solid legal statement on handling military debris _naysayers_ ... you are the absolute mad lad!

Comment: @GlennWillen, one of the good things about *.stack is that it focuses on providing answers to questions asked, and is not filled with a lot of editorializing.  That being said, every user can edit or suggest edits to every answer.  If you feel you can improve the answer, you should do so.  Other users will provide feedback they feel appropriate.

Comment: Legal issues aside, do archeology, investigators, and the museum a solid and document when and where you found it. Without that it’s just a hunk of metal.

Comment: @candied_orange I think that some manufacturers have geotagging enabled by default, which the museum could use if one sends the original file.

Comment: **I don't see any reason at all to editorialize this fine answer**, I'm afraid @GlennWillen.  Such things are appropriate for comments.  aviation is (easily) the most sensible, consistent, and least-idiotic of all the SO sites.  (People who couldn't care a hoot about airplanes, read this site for that reason alone!!)  Pls do not let standards slip.

Answer (score 4):

I am a retired journalist and lifelong aviation buff/writer/researcher in St. John's. I conducted an in-depth research project into this crash and published the results in a two part, front page story in the Telegram newspaper in 2015. Since the crash of a T-33 is the only one known to have taken place in Logy Bay, I'd say the chances of it being a piece of the plane are excellent (it is obviously a piece of aircraft aluminum).